# How can I make my own iPhone app for myself?

Tags: iphone

I don't have an Apple computer, I just have an iPhone and some knowledge about language development. I want to create my own app for my own use, just for fun! I don't want to pay Apple for a developer account. I just want to develop my app and put it on my iPhone. I can either develop on Linux or Windows. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to develop on an actual iPhone, you'll need a developer licence. To developer apps natively you will need a Mac running XCode. 
There's lots of HTML5 libraries for making apps using javascript though. Maybe try out Phonegap or GameSalad

Comment: Not legally. It is a breach of the OSX EULA to run OSX on anything except Apple hardware.

Comment: I just want to create my app in my little directory on my little computer, and somehow put the executable on my phone... ^^

Comment: you **cannot** run native iOS applications on your phone without a developer licence. It's as simple as that.

Comment: No. Applications on the iPhone are signed by the developer, for security. You can jailbreak and run what you like, but you'll still need a Mac to have access to the Cocoa Touch framework. If you're desperate not to have a mac, use a HTML5 library like phonegap.

Comment: @MaxWoolf Ok, Phonegap isn't what I want, this is for web apps. I would like to make a game. So looks like it's not possible... Is there the same problems on Android ?

Comment: No, you can do what you want with android. It's an open platform built on Java which is cross platform.

Answer (score 2):

At the minimum you'll need to have OSX (Mac Operating system) to run Xcode/iphone emulator, you wont be able to do this without OSX.

EDIT:
  You may be able to develop it using phone gap: http://phonegap.com/ 
  You'll have to do testing on an adriod emulator, but I believe phonegap builds the app in the cloud.  Good luck.

Comment: Even if I have a Linux OS ? OSX is just an overlay of a linux.

Comment: OSX isn't 'just an overlay of Linux'. It's based off the Unix core, but has a different kernel.

Comment: "I believe phonegap builds the app in the cloud" I don't want to put my app on the cloud or the apple store, only my phone.

Comment: It builds in the cloud, but it isn't available to everyone. If you want it on your phone, you **will** need a developer licence.

Comment: "I believe phonegap builds the app in the cloud" Build means compiling it from source code to something that a computer can run.

Comment: "you will need a developer licence". Can't I create an app on my computer and put the executable somehow on my phone? =/

Comment: @Elfayer To do that you must have a Jailbroken phone or a developer account. No other options.

Comment: @MatthewGraves Ok, well... I wasn't expecting more from Apple. Is it the same for Android ?

Comment: No, android development and distribution is free.

Comment: Even if only run this app on your device, you still need a developer license.  This is because you will need to create a "Distribution" certificate with any test device UUID.  You will need a mac to create, build, and sign this certificate into your application IPA.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop an app using adobe AIR or adobe Flash.  Check out FlashDevelop for a free solution for making flash and air apps for everything from windows to android to iOS.

For a somewhat detailed tutorial on how to actually export an AIR project from FlashDevelop so you can install it on an iOS device, see:

http://www.codeandvisual.com/2011/exporting-for-iphone-using-air-27-and-flashdevelop-part-one-installation/

and FYI, this is not JUST for jailbroken iOS devices!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Native iOS applications can only be built in Xcode (which can only run on a Mac), and you need a developer membership to deploy those on an actual device (which costs about $100 a year). So, that’s the caveat: You can’t make native apps.

However, native apps aren’t the only option! There are two other approaches.

One way is to make a web app. These days, web apps can do almost everything that a native app can do (even access the camera). Unless you’re building something specialized (like a video editor, for example, or a game that needs to work with Bluetooth game controllers), you can probably make something as a web app. Years ago, I wasn’t happy with the flashcard apps on the market and wanted something custom but super simple to help me study JLPT vocabulary. At the time, I also didn’t have the money for a developer membership. I made it as a web app, and it worked great!

If you’re making a web app, you’ll need someplace to host it. There are lots of options. For example, the free tier on Firebase is plenty for a personal-use web app. You also might want to consider building the app using client-side scripting (like Javascript) so that you can host it statically, which will allow you to tell iOS to cache it so you can utilize it offline (Google “HTML offline manifest” for details).

The other way, if you have a friend with a developer account, is to build your app using a cross-platform framework like Flutter, where you don’t need a Mac to develop and test it, then ask your friend to make it for you. You’ll need to rebuild periodically (I think once a year) because your provisioning profile will expire.

If you use a framework like Flutter that can build both native AND web apps, that gives you the ability to run natively (if you have access to a Mac) or host it statically on someplace like Firebase Hosting (if you don’t).